# How can I allow users of my connector to set a different username and password each time they create a new source?

Tags: looker-studio

I have build and published the Data Studio connector for TradeTracker. The connector works great, but when users try to add a different account by trying to add a new datasource they can't re-enter their API Clientid and passphrase. How do I clear the 'old' credentials?

I have found there's an function to reset the auth: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth#resetauth.

```
function resetAuth() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.deleteProperty('dscc.username');
  userProperties.deleteProperty('dscc.password');
}
```

When should I call this function?

You can find the data studio connector here: https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/datasources/create

Search for 'tradetracker'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple auth profiles are not currently supported by Data Studio. If you want to authenticate to a data source with different credentials, you need to remove the connector (which will call `resetAuth`), then add it again and use your new credentials.

If this feature would be useful to you, please [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:321382), or vote on an existing one. We look at this component in part when trying to prioritize new features for Data Studio.